# Making sense of the log after a BSOD in Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod, error-logging, windows-error-reporting

I got a Blue Screen and the computer restarted automatically. After the restart I got a message in a dialog box, and it asked whether I wanted to search online for a solution. However, I just closed the dialog box and restarted the computer again. The message in the dialogue box is as follows:

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  BlueScreen   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1   Locale ID:   1033
>
> Additional information about the problem:   BCCode:   1000008e
>   BCP1: C0000005   BCP2:    99D4139A   BCP3:    B910DB14   BCP4:    00000000   OS
>   Version:  6_1_7600   Service Pack:    0_0   Product:  256_1
>
> Files that help describe the problem:
>   C:\Windows\Minidump\050314-33259-01.dmp
>   C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-55879-0.sysdata.xml
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

I tried to open the minidump file. When opening the folder it asked me to get permanent access to the folder and I could then open the folder, but it still doesn't let me open the .dmp file. The second .xml file does not exist. Is it possible to analyse this message to understand what the problem was?

Answer (score 1):

You Can view it with a Third Party Tool `BlueScreenView`
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Answer (score 1):

You should first install the Windows 7 Sp1 (6.1.7601), you still use the Win7 RTM version (6.1.7600).

If you still get crashes, you can [analyze the dumps with Windbg](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) and look for details about the [Bug Check 0x1000008E: KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you got.